# How to wite PHP code with the following SQL query?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to query out a result, it works in SQL query, but I'm trying to get the result using PHP

```
SELECT prs_amtdb FROM `prs` WHERE prs_amtcrck = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `prs_amtdb` FROM prs WHERE `prs_amtcrck` = 0");
$results = $query->fetchAll();

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

If you have user input that you're using in your query you should always use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) eg:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `prs_amtdb` FROM prs WHERE `prs_amtcrck` = :atmcrck");
$query->bindParam(':atmcrck', 0); // 0 will be the user input
$query->execute();    
$results = $query->fetchAll();

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result;
}
```

Make sure you have a database connection setup in PDO:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: I appreciate it's not necessary to use parameterisation on fixed values, but it is worth pointing out that if the zero comes from user input, parameterisation is a good idea from a security perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Using mysqli

Note: Make sure you bind your value. mysqli does not automatically 
        secure your query
    $connection=  mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

```
$query="SELECT prs_amtdb FROM prs WHERE prs_amtcrck = 0";

$result=  mysqli_query($connection, $query);//$connection is your database

//connection

//fetch the result

while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['column_name'].'<br/>';
}
```